# How to compress or Zip whole folder using GZipStream

Tags: gzipstream

Any idea how I can do this? I am able to compress a single file.

Comment: Most likely C#: [System.IO.Compression.GZipStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

You cannot GZip an entire folder directly, since GZip operates on a single stream of data.  You will first have to turn the folder into such a stream.

One way to do this would be to create a [Tar archive](http://code.google.com/p/tar-cs/) from the directory.  This will give you a single stream to work on, and since the Tar format is not compressed, GZip will usually achieve good compression ratios on Tar files.

Answer (score 1):

GZip doesn't support multiple files.  They have to be combined in another container first like Tar.  If you need full Zip support for C# use this library:

http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/